# How to exclude <!-- --> from registering by Cufon and converting to canvas

Tags: javascript, cufon

For example I have this code:

```
<div id="block-login">
  <a href="#"><!-- --></a>  
  <a href="log-reg">LOGIN / REGISTRATION</a>
</div>
```

In hy header I have this:

```
<script>
  Cufon.replace('#block-login', { fontFamily: 'Myriad Pro' });
</script>
```

My question is, how to make link with the comment not registered by Cufon. Is it posssible to set something like that in settings of cufon via javascript?

So, in the result only links with something in them (text) would be converted to cufon canvas and other commented links will be left alone without conversion.

Because now it makes me a lot of problems when converted commented stuff; it adds them height and width, which distort my design. Before using Cufon it was OK.

Comment: The more important question: Why using cufon? Webfonts are [supported in every browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=font-face) you could possibly think of... even IE6 can handle it!

Answer (score 1):

How about adding the ID or a class only to the parts you want Cufon to transform?

```
<div id="block-login">
  <a href="#"><!-- --></a>  
  <a href="log-reg" class="something">LOGIN / REGISTRATION</a>
</div>
```

Then you can call it directly with:

```
Cufon.replace('.something', { fontFamily: 'Myriad Pro' });
```

I had a quick look through their [API docs](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/API) and the closest thing I could find to what you're asking for was their `ignoreClass` option:

> Allows you to ignore elements based on a single or multiple class names. If an element matches one of the class names, it will not be processed by Cufón. Its children will be left alone too.

This requires you to add a class to things you want to ignore.

From personal experience I've always used a class like `cufon` and just put it on the things that need Cufon applied, if I knew it would always be applied to specific elements I'd just use a generic tag name (e.g. `Cufon.replace('h1')`).